# SKScene FPS dropping on transition with Xamarin

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, sprite-kit, frame-rate

Problem with SKScenes.
I have two SKScenes. Both have some static nodes on them. They are associated with different ViewControllers. When I perform a transition from Scene1 to Scene2 (and the other way round) the initial scene seems to be removed (.Dispose() method is called and it seems to be redrawn according to debug output). But after 2-3 transitions there and back FPS gradually fall from 30 to 10 or less (!). It seems that the scene is still in memory. What should I do to dispose the scene properly?

```
public override void ViewWillLayoutSubviews ()
    {
        base.ViewWillLayoutSubviews ();
        var skView = (SKView)View;
        if (skView.Scene == null) {
            Console.WriteLine ("Scene is to be created");
            skView.ShowsFPS = true;
            skView.ShowsNodeCount = true;

            // Create and configure the scene.
            var scene = new MatchmakingView (skView.Bounds.Size);

            scene.ScaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.AspectFill;

            // Present the scene.
            skView.PresentScene (scene);

            scene.OnToWaiting += _OnToWaiting;
            scene.OnToMain += _OnToMain;
        }

    }

public override void ViewDidDisappear (bool animated)
    {
        base.ViewDidDisappear (animated);
        var skView = (SKView)View;
        var scene = (MatchmakingView)skView.Scene;
        scene.OnToWaiting -= _OnToWaiting;
        scene.OnToMain -= _OnToMain;
        skView.RemoveFromSuperview ();
        scene.Dispose ();
        skView.Dispose ();
        Console.WriteLine ("MMa removed");
    }
```